# Changing the paper size

Tags: paper-size

I have been using the `currvita.tex` template located [here](http://www.cv-templates.info/2009/10/classicthesis-currvita-latex-cv-template/) with TeXShop. Unfortunately, the output is not 8.5" by 11". Is there some way I can change either TeXShop settings or the TeX document to adjust the page size?

Comment: Carsten answers your question, but note that you don't have to use `scrartcl`. `currvita.sty` works quite well with the `article` class.

Comment: I've posted a similar question for the `memoir` class here: [Customizing Page Size in Memoir](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39273)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The template uses the [KOMA](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/koma-script.html) documentclass `scrartcl`. You can switch to letter paper by replacing the first line with

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{scrartcl}
```

You will probably have to play around with the layout as it is optimized for a4 pages.

Comment: You also need to pass the `pagesize` option, see [Why does setting the paper size with KOMA-Script require TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5873/5874#5874)

Comment: This should be `\documentclass[paper=letter]{scrartcl}`. See pg. 48 of the `scrartcl` package.

Answer (score 12):

Carsten's suggestion is good, just to add some other possible ways of changing page parameters.

A very quick and dirty hack, just after the `\begin{document}` add:

```
  \pdfpageheight 8.5in 
  \pdfpagewidth 11in
```

For a different way - to get finer control use the [geometry](http://ctan.um.ac.ir/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf) package (just change the parameters to suit)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}    % classe article di KOMA
\usepackage[total={6.5in,8.75in},top=1.2in,
  left=0.9in, includefoot]{geometry}
```

Comment: the direct command didn't work. The only thing that geometry package did was to mess up with my figure without noticing any affect on the actual document size.

Comment: +1 `\pdfpage...size` worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

For changing TeXShop directly, add:

```
--extradvipsopts "-t letter"
```

to the `simpdftex` command in TeXShop->Preferences->Engine->TeX + dvips + distiller and then use Tex and DVI when typesetting.