# Customizing Page Size in Memoir

Tags: memoir, paper-size

How do I customize the size of the output pages in the `memoir class`?

For example, how could I change the page size to `6x9` (while preserving the margin proportions and headers/footers I use) in the following MWE?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}

% customize
\setstocksize{297mm}{210mm}
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{195mm}{*}
\settypeblocksize{671.6pt}{335.8pt}{*}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{4}
\setulmargins{*}{*}{2}
\setmarginnotes{5mm}{45.23mm}{\onelineskip}
\setlength{\footskip}{3.0\baselineskip}
\checkandfixthelayout

% headers and footers
\nouppercaseheads
\makepagestyle{mystyle} 
\setlength{\headwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}
\makerunningwidth{mystyle}{\headwidth}
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{\itshape\leftmark}{}{}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{}{\itshape\leftmark}
\makeevenfoot{mystyle}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{mystyle}{}{}{\thepage}
\makepsmarks{mystyle}{\createmark{chapter}{left}{}{}{}}
\makeatletter
\makepsmarks{mystyle}{\createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{:\ }}
\makeatother
\makepagestyle{plain}
\makerunningwidth{plain}{\headwidth}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{\thepage}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}
Here is some text.
\end{document}
```

P.S.  Currently, my document has `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}` at the top--does this control the page size?

Comment: You could use [the `geometry` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/).

Comment: Do not use geometry and memoir together, as they will fight for use of lengths. Memoir has all you need. Also keep in mind that stocksize is the whole PDF area, and trimmedsize is the finished area. Sometimes trimmed is smaller than stock. If so, you probably need to center trim within stock, using trimtop and trimedge. Margins are always measured relative to trim, not stock.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) provides its own set of page layout macros, it's best to use them rather than resort to something like [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry). Also, using `a4paper` followed `\setstocksize{297mm}{210mm}` is superfluous, since `a4paper` has those dimensions exactly. In fact, if you choose the document class option `a4paper` with `memoir`, it executes `\stockaiv`, which is defined as

```
\newcommand*{\stockaiv} {\stockheight=297mm \stockwidth=210mm}
```

So, either use `a4paper` *or* `\setstocksize{297mm}{210mm}`, but not both.

In order to *reduce* the page size from `297mm` x `210mm` to `9in` x `6in` "while preserving the margin proportions and headers/footers", I would figure out the ratios between the two sizes knowing that

```
1mm ~  2.84526pt
1in ~ 72.26999pt
```

As such, the following settings are used:

```
\documentclass[11pt,showtrims]{memoir}

% Original setup
% \setstocksize{297mm}{210mm}
% \settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{195mm}{*}
% \settypeblocksize{671.6pt}{335.8pt}{*}

% New setup
\setstocksize{9in}{6in}
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\dimexpr 6in-15mm}{*}
\settypeblocksize{516.9312pt}{243.6962pt}{*}
```

It kept the same proportions between the page size and the text block, but kept the trimming margins the same (`15mm` less than `\stockwidth`). The original is shown on the left, while the new is shown on the right at the same resolution (for comparison purposes):

[image]

Comment: Is `\checkandfixthelayout` needed for the new layout to be applied in mid-document? Also, do you change layout before or after a newpage?