# Problems in customizing Memoir page size

Tags: formatting, memoir, paper-size

I have followed the suggestions proposed in:

[Customizing Page Size in Memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39273/customizing-page-size-in-memoir)

to customize Memoir page size, and although the page size changes, the text block doesn't fit the page. It seems that the text keeps fixed in the A4 format.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The text block does not automatically adjust it self after which paper size is chosen.