# How to handle large images?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, paper-size

I am using tikz to generate an image which is wider than the the available space for the document. The figure will be later added to another document. When I watch the figure in my document reader (evince) it is cut. I tried to use

```
\special{papersize=200mm,400mm}
```

without any apparent affect. How can view the entire image then?

Thanks

Comment: see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7476/7049

Comment: is scaling an option? you can add the option `scale=0.5` or some other factor to the picture.

Comment: Have you thought of adding a `scale=number` key-value combination to the `tikzpicture`?

Answer (score 1):

The safest method, in my opinion, is to issue

```
\usepackage[pass,papersize={200mm,400mm}]{geometry}
```

With the `pass` option the package won't change the default margins and overall setup chosen by the class, but will send the appropriate commands for the engine or driver used (`pdftex` for pdfLaTeX, `dvips` for LaTeX, `xdvipdfmx` for XeLaTeX) which are automatically detected. If another driver is used, it can be passed as

```
driver=dvipdfm
driver=vtex
```

(for those two particular printing driver and engine).

You can also use `geometry` for setting everything else about pagination (see the manual).